# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=13.100.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild

I am attempting to run a build in TFS 2018. We also have SQL Server 2016 installed on the TFS build server (which is Windows Server 2016). Visual Studio is 2017. The first solution file produces the following error, and I have no idea from where this file is referenced:
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8607312Z Package:
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8608029Z   Invoking Web Deploy to generate the package with the following settings:
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8608667Z   $(LocalIisVersion) is 10
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8609527Z   $(DestinationIisVersion) is 10
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8610846Z   $(UseIis) is True
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8612479Z   $(IisUrl) is http://localhost:62327/
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8614266Z   $(IncludeIisSettings) is False
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8615630Z   $(_DeploymentUseIis) is False
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8617245Z   $(DestinationUseIis) is False
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8666548Z GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles:
2019-01-22T20:35:26.8684620Z   Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
2019-01-22T20:35:27.0589951Z **Visual Studio is 2017. ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets(119,5): Error MSB4018: The "SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables" task failed unexpectedly.**
**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=13.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**
File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=13.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.SqlScriptPreprocessor.SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Can you build the same solution locally?

Comment: Yes, I can. But the TFS Build Definition keeps failing. The Visual Studio machine is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: So you have that assembly on your local machine but not on the build server.  Have a look at this and see if it helps... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25216/publishing-error-with-missing-microsoftsqlserverba.html

Comment: No, I don't have that assembly on the Visual Studio machine.  I do have Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll, Version=14.0.3026.27.

Comment: It will be using that version.  If you look in the app.config, in the runtime section, you'll probably see an assembly binding that basically says "use version X of this assembly when asked for version Y".  You just need to ensure that the assembly is also available on the build server.  You could install the software that includes that assembly, or you could include the DLL specifically in your application, by creating a folder within your project, copying the DLL into it, and then changing your project reference to point to that copy of the DLL, instead of just using the global cache.

Comment: Is this version of the DLL deployed via the NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects)?

Answer (score 1):

Found the same [workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/226962/publishing-web-deploy-packages-with-included-sql-s.html) that [Michiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3331185/michiel-de-wolde) referred to.

My situation:

- Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools (no IDE)
- Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser Version=13.100.0.0 not registered in
  the Global Assembly Cache. Neither was 13.0.0.0.
- VS Build Tools does not include Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll. The path referenced is for VS Enterprise and does not exist for Build Tools: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\130`. There is no similar path under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools`
- I checked install of Build Tools. Said that SQL Server Data Tools was installed - under Data Storage and Processing workload

My solution:

- Per recommendation [here](https://wokoask.com/questions/visual-studio-2015-exception-sqlscriptpreprocesssqlvariables-when-running-web-publish-wizard-with-update-database-19050101.html), I downloaded and installed SQL Server Data Tools followed by a reboot.
- That got Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser Version=13.0.0.0 registered in the Global Assembly Cache
- Then, per workaround in question (developercommunity above), I added a binding redirect for MSBuild (in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\BinMSBuild.exe.config` - see below)
- Fixed.

```
<!-- Workaround for errorMSB4018: The "SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=13.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. -->
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/226962/publishing-web-deploy-packages-with-included-sql-s.html), for the desktop build. Did not try the TFS team build.

Use gacutil to register Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser v2015.130.1601.5 installed with Visual Studio 2017, apparently satisfying build task SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables even if it requested v13.100.0.0.

In:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\130
```

or similar issue:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll
```

or similar.

2023-02-14 The issue occurred again, now using Visual Studio 2022. The following workaround fixed the issue.

VS2022 now runs in 64 bit. Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll built for 64 bit should be used. Also adding assemblies to the GAC is now discouraged. Instead copy the assembly from the installation location of VS2022, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\150
```

to the correct MSBuild folder. Several MSBuild folders may be around, use the 64 bit folder actually used by VS2022, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64
```

Build task SqlScriptPreprocessor.SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables resides in assembly Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. That assembly asks for version 13.100.0.0 of Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll. Version 13.100.0.0 cannot be used; it results in "Invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file". Instead add an assembly redirect for MSBuild. In for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe.config
```

add

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="15.100.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

15.100.0.0 being the assembly version of Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll; ignore any file version such as 2018.150.1000.16.